# Java Exception - TransactionRolledbackLocalException

Tags: java, exception, glassfish, ejb

I have a Java project that I write in Netbeans on Glassfish server. It was working fine till today. Today I am getting an exception like this:

```
Exception Handler


Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the web application. Please review the following stack trace for more information regarding the error.

Exception Details: com.bla.bla.persistence.business.exceptions.ReportJPAException
  null

Possible Source of Error:
   Class Name: com.bla.bla.persistence.business.exceptions.EclipseLinkExceptionHandler
   File Name: EclipseLinkExceptionHandler.java
   Method Name: handleException
   Line Number: 21

Source not available. Information regarding the location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

com.bla.bla.persistence.business.exceptions.EclipseLinkExceptionHandler.handleException(EclipseLinkExceptionHandler.java:21)
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.handleException(AbstractSession.java:2235)
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithPreBuiltChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1553)
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.writeChanges(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:360)
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.flush(EntityManagerImpl.java:610)
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.performPreQueryFlush(EJBQueryImpl.java:1182)
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.executeReadQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:404)
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.getResultList(EJBQueryImpl.java:669)
com..bla.bla.persistence.business.GenericJpaController.executeQuery(GenericJpaController.java:72)
com.bla.bla.persistence.business.GenericJpaController.getLast(GenericJpaController.java:81)
com..bla.bla.persistence.business.GenericJpaController.getLast(GenericJpaController.java:86)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1047)
org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1119)
com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5203)
com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:610)
com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:797)
com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:562)
com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:157)
com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:139)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor71.invoke( Unknown Source )
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:858)
com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:797)
com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:367)
com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5175)
com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5163)
com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:190)
com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:84)
$Proxy607.getLast( Unknown Source )
com.bla.bla.persistence.business.lrms.__EJB31_Generated__ReportJpaController__Intf____Bean__.getLast( Unknown Source )
com.bla.bla.service.ReportRegisterService.register(ReportRegisterService.java:61)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1047)
org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1119)
com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5203)
com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:610)
com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:797)
com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:562)
com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:157)
com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:139)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor71.invoke( Unknown Source )
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:858)
com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:797)
com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:367)
com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5175)
com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5163)
com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:190)
com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:84)
$Proxy567.register( Unknown Source )
com.bla.bla.service.__EJB31_Generated__ReportRegisterService__Intf____Bean__.register( Unknown Source )
com.bla.bla.faces.user.webreports.webfilteroverview.submitReportRequest(webfilteroverview.java:405)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:234)
com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
com.sun.rave.web.ui.appbase.faces.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:91)
javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
com.sun.webui.jsf.component.WebuiCommand.broadcast(WebuiCommand.java:160)
javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:774)
javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1266)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:82)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:312)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
com.sun.webui.jsf.util.UploadFilter.doFilter(UploadFilter.java:267)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
com.bla.lcas.client.filters.SingleSignOutNameAddFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutNameAddFilter.java:56)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
org.jasig.cas.client.util.AssertionThreadLocalFilter.doFilter(AssertionThreadLocalFilter.java:40)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
org.jasig.cas.client.util.HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter.doFilter(HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter.java:50)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractTicketValidationFilter.doFilter(AbstractTicketValidationFilter.java:167)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
com.bla.lcas.client.filters.LCASAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(LCASAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:104)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
com..bla.bla.web.filter.LocaleFilter.doFilter(LocaleFilter.java:76)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:277)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:329)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:233)
org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:229)
org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:334)
org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:814)
org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:743)
org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:936)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:682)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Exception Details: javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException
  Exception thrown from bean

Possible Source of Error:
   Class Name: com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer
   File Name: BaseContainer.java
   Method Name: checkExceptionClientTx
   Line Number: 4886

Source not available. Information regarding the location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.checkExceptionClientTx(BaseContainer.java:4886)
com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4721)
com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1941)
com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1892)
com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:198)
com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:84)
$Proxy607.getLast( Unknown Source )
com..bla.bla.persistence.business.lrms.__EJB31_Generated__ReportJpaController__Intf____Bean__.getLast( Unknown Source )
com.bla.bla.service.ReportRegisterService.register(ReportRegisterService.java:61)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1047)
org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1119)
com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5203)
com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:610)
com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:797)
com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:562)
com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:157)
com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:139)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor71.invoke( Unknown Source )
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:858)
com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:797)
com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:367)
com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5175)
com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5163)
com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:190)
com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:84)
$Proxy567.register( Unknown Source )
com.bla.bla.service.__EJB31_Generated__ReportRegisterService__Intf____Bean__.register( Unknown Source )
com.bla.bla.faces.user.webreports.webfilteroverview.submitReportRequest(webfilteroverview.java:405)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:234)
com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
com.sun.rave.web.ui.appbase.faces.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:91)
javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
com.sun.webui.jsf.component.WebuiCommand.broadcast(WebuiCommand.java:160)
javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:774)
javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1266)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:82)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:312)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
com.sun.webui.jsf.util.UploadFilter.doFilter(UploadFilter.java:267)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
com.bla.lcas.client.filters.SingleSignOutNameAddFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutNameAddFilter.java:56)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
org.jasig.cas.client.util.AssertionThreadLocalFilter.doFilter(AssertionThreadLocalFilter.java:40)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
org.jasig.cas.client.util.HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter.doFilter(HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter.java:50)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractTicketValidationFilter.doFilter(AbstractTicketValidationFilter.java:167)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
com.bla.lcas.client.filters.LCASAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(LCASAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:104)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
com.bla.bla.web.filter.LocaleFilter.doFilter(LocaleFilter.java:76)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:277)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:329)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:233)
org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:229)
org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:334)
org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:814)
org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:743)
org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:936)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:682)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Exception Details: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException
  null

Possible Source of Error:
   Class Name: com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer
   File Name: BaseContainer.java
   Method Name: mapLocal3xException
   Line Number: 2190

Source not available. Information regarding the location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.mapLocal3xException(BaseContainer.java:2190)
com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1990)
com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1892)
com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:198)
com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:84)
$Proxy607.getLast( Unknown Source )
com.bla.bla.persistence.business.lrms.__EJB31_Generated__ReportJpaController__Intf____Bean__.getLast( Unknown Source )
com.bla.bla.service.ReportRegisterService.register(ReportRegisterService.java:61)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1047)
org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1119)
com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5203)
com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:610)
com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:797)
com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:562)
com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:157)
com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:139)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor71.invoke( Unknown Source )
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:858)
com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:797)
com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:367)
com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5175)
com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5163)
com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:190)
com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:84)
$Proxy567.register( Unknown Source )
com.bla.bla.service.__EJB31_Generated__ReportRegisterService__Intf____Bean__.register( Unknown Source )
com..bla.bla.faces.user.webreports.webfilteroverview.submitReportRequest(webfilteroverview.java:405)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:234)
com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
```

This project and neither of my project are working now. Does anyone have any idea about this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe it's related with the DB connection. please, try to ping the database, or to delete and add again the connection in your IDE.

Best regards.

Comment: it was a little bit old question :) as far as I remember, I solved it by killing Java and restarting Tomcat. Thanks anyway :)